# Help with web host's phpMyAdmin! Error #1064!

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064, web-hosting

This is the weirdest thing, when I try to edit or delete any records, or use a query with a WHERE. The result is a #1064 error every single time.
Here's the input,

```
SELECT * FROM user_names WHERE username='value'
```

Here's the result

```
Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if       there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 40
STR: =\
SQL: SELECT * FROM user_names WHERE username=\'value\'

SQL query: 

SELECT * FROM user_names WHERE username=\'value\'

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'value\'' at line 1
```

When I go back to edit the query backslashes have been added behind the quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM user_names WHERE username=\\\'value\\\'
```

I have uninstalled and installed phpMyAdmin several times and it has done nothing. I did recently upgrade the to the php version 5.3.6. This is happening on the web host, not on local. Please advise in anyway possible!

Comment: Strange error, (username='value') should work. Try this - (username="value").

Comment: rather strange, try run the query in cli to see of if it's a db issue, if not, run the query in simple php script to see if it's the new version php. then on phpadmin, escalate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got magic_quotes enabled somewhere in your php ini

(IIRC there are multiple aliases for this e.g. magic_quotes_sybase which behave in subtley different ways - and once **any** are enabled, they can't be disabled).

magic_quotes have been deprecated for some time. Fix your config

Comment: I used the phpinfo on the webhost and magic_quotes_gpc is on. How do I turn it off? I have no access to the hosting provider's php.ini file.

Comment: Ask your hosting company to get their finger out or change hosting provider.

Comment: Yeah definitely looking into it. Funds are a bit short at the moment and locked into a year-long contract with this provider :(